Is "Canada's nation's capital" a mistake?
A quick search reveals that constructions like "Canada's nation's capital" or "America's nation's central bank" are in common usage, including in very widely read news publications.
I've always believed a duplicated possessive indicates a sequence in which each object is actually possessed by the one prior, for example "Mike's dog's bowl" where the dog is Mike's. But I have never heard that a country can possess the nation which it is.
Am I wrong, are they wrong, or is there a special rule or turn of phrase at play here?
More examples, and of other "jurisdictional levels":

"America's nation's security"
"China's nation's painful memories"
"West Germany's nation's political and economic awakening"
"California's state's emergency drought proclamation"
"Pittsburgh's city's oldest and largest synagogue"
Here's a case of someone actually saying "Canada's nation's capital of Ottawa", strongly suggesting that this is not a typo.


A lot of those look like simple errors, e.g. they've written "the nation's security" and then decided to specify what nation it was, but they've not fully changed the wording. But thanks for actually including examples, which most questioners don't.

Seems to me that each example works better without the unnecessary nation's, state's, or city's. Pittsburgh is already a city, though I could see "Pittsburgh's suburb's oldest .."

There are a lot of grammatical mistakes in widely read news publications. The stories are published in a hurry and they have things to be concerned with other than grammar (such as not getting sued for libel).

"Canada's nation's capital" and "America's nation's central bank" sound bad to me, but there is a way to interpret them as grammatical constructions.
Forms ending in 's can be used in (at least) two different ways. The most common way is to take a noun phrase, such as "the nation" or "my dog", and add 's to the entire phrase: "the nation's". Then you use this whole phrase ending in 's like a determiner, replacing a word like "a(n)" or "the" or "its": "[the nation's] central bank" or "[my dog's] bowl".
However, there are also cases where 's is added to a noun and it forms something that acts as an attributive modifier (like an adjective) to a following noun. This does not take the place of a determiner, but occupies a separate role in the phrase. This is called a "classifying genitive".
Examples of the classifying genitive construction include "a children's book" or "a master's degree". You can't say "a children", so obviously "a children's book" must be divided as "a [children's book]", not as "[a children's] book".
If we interpret "nation's" as a classifying genitive, then it could be preceded by another genitive that plays the role of a determiner, giving us phrases like the ones you asked about. In other words, we can interpret "Canada's nation's capital" not as "[Canada's nation's] capital", but as "Canada's [nation's capital]", equivalent to "The [nation's capital] of Canada". I would prefer to say "Canada's national capital"/"the national capital of Canada", but there isn't any specific rule I know of that prohibits using "nation's" as a classifying genitive, aside from custom or usage. So if some people find this usage natural, it would be as grammatical for them as a phrase like "Anna's master's degree" (which means "the master's degree of Anna", not "the degree of Anna's master").

Agree with the answer in general, although in this case I think we would normally say "national" instead of "nation's": "Canada's national capital". We would use the possessive form for genitives that don't have a distinct word like this.

An extension of this point would be: This pattern is idiomatic where we encounter established idiomatic phrases containing the genitive, like "master's degree." Where we don't, it doesn't communicate comfortably and naturally and, "legal" or not, is a poor choice.

@AndyBonner: Even when using established phrases, using a classifying genitive construction along with a possessive should generally be avoided whenever practical.  If Mary has children, books they own might be described as "Mary's children's books", but "Mary's books for children" should probably not be described likewise.

@supercat Some are quite happy to distinguish "Mary's childrens books" from "Mary's children's books" nowadays.

@EdwinAshworth In speech they're indistinguishable. But context will often disambiguate: Is Mary a known writer; does she have children?

@Barmar I'd differentiate in speech: [Mary's] .. [childrens books] {where .. signals a slight pause}, with slight stress on childrens, for books for children authored/owned by Mary, vs [Mary's children's books]. 'Books' is destressed in both.

@EdwinAshworth "childrens" not being in the dictionary (MW) could complicate that  a little.

@traktor There are probably more examples of Working Mens Clubs than apostrophised ones. This phenomenon has been discussed elsewhere on ELU.

It's not a grammatical mistake, but it is a logical mistake and is unnecessary.
"Canada's nation's capital" means exactly the same as "Canada's capital". The extra word adds nothing at all to meaning or implication. Adding unnecessary words is poor form at best.
Also note that there is no such thing as "Canada's nation". When we talk of the "Nation of Canada" it's not a possessive. Canada does not have a nation is is a nation. And a thing that doesn't exist cannot have a capital. We can talk about "The nation of Canada", which is not a possessive; but the use of the apostrophe indicates the possessive, which is wrong.
(There are "nations" that make up Canada - The First Nations, the Meti Nation, the Francophone Nation - but to make sense you would have to specify which nation you meant, and in fact none of those nations have capitals.)
If you wish to emphasize that the capital in question is the capital of the nation itself, and not the capital of a lesser entity  that happens to be in Canada, then you can say "Canada's national capital".

Canada's nation is as acceptable as Wight's Isle or  The Bulge's Battle. There are various different isoformal usages including an of-phrase. Some can't be reformulated using a Saxon genitive. _A heart of gold / a man of noble descent / a man of character / a woman of the world / a fool of a husband / a dislike of hard work / the nation of Canada.

Well, Canada has all sorts of nations. The First Nations and the newcomers... if the phrase (or context) clarified that it goes about a particular nation residing in Canada, that phrase could relate to that "nation's capital" (not necessarily Ottawa as the political country's capital). A bit of a stretch, but could be seen as reasonable :D

@EdwinAshworth Yes, it's about as acceptable as those. Which is to say, never used.

@JimKlimov Very very much a stretch. And if it meant one of the nations that makes up Canada (which would be extremely unusual usage) then it's not a good sentence because it does not specify which one. It would be as unlikely as saying "America's state capital". Is that Harrisburg? Juneau?

The reasoning in the comment makes it a grammatical mistake, not only a matter of non-idiomacy.

Canada is a nation but it isn't a Nation; it's the Dominion of Canada, thanks to the United Kingdom (of Great Britain and Ireland, at that time) uniting the provinces in the Constitution Act 1867. Similarly, there's the state of Massachusetts, but not State of Massachusetts, because it's the Commonwealth of Massachusetts.

I mean, to be fair: "Canada's capital" is C, "Canada's nation's capital" is Ottawa.  @user71659 Canada self instantiated itself long after 1867 (most recently in 1982); it is not really any longer the Dominion of Canada; it is an obsolete name for the nation.  The same entity, no longer known by that name other than in historic documents.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont No. "Canada's capital is 'C'" is a schoolboy joke, which is not meant to be taken seriously. "Canada's nation's capital" is exactly what I talk about in the answer. The rest of your sentences aren't really relevant to the answer.

'The Nation of Canada' does not use the Norman / periphrastic genitive in the same way that 'The climate of Canada' does.
The usage is listed in Merriam-Webster:

of
...
8a — used as a function word to indicate a particular example
belonging to the class denoted by the preceding noun

the city of Rome


This usage of 'of', not being genitive, not showing ownership or a related 'belonging', does not permit the Saxon genitive paraphrase:

*Liberty's Statue

*The Rights' Bill

*Nod's Land.


There may be the very occasional counterexample in poetry, lyrics:

In Dublin's fair city ....

.............................
Canada's nation is as acceptable as Wight's Isle or The Bulge's Battle.
There are various different isoformal usages including an of-phrase. Some can't be reformulated using a Saxon genitive.

a heart of gold
a man of noble descent
a man of character
a woman of the world
a fool of a husband
a dislike of hard work
the nation of Canada.


The main point is the non-genitive for nation of [country].

ELU answers are better when thorough.
